# Configure git for Azure and GitHUB and BitBucket on one system

Tags: git, azure, version-control, bitbucket

i am working on multiple projects with different teams and using GitHub, Azure and Bitbucket, i use VSCode for my development.
please how can i use different individual settings for each of them, since i have different accounts created for these platforms.

at the moment i have this global setting for GitHub alone.

```
 git config --global user.name ande caleb
 git config --global user.email ande.caleb@microsoft.com
```

i now want to include Azure and Bitbucket, but i dont know how to go about that.

Is there a way to keep the global settings and still push and commit to other platforms(azure, bitbucket) with different credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can define different user name & email per project

### `--local`

Instead of defining the configuration globally define it locally per project

```
git config --local user.name ande caleb
git config --local user.email ande.caleb@microsoft.com
```

#### Deep explanation:

Git store configuration is "levels", each of these “levels” (system, global, local) overwrites values in the previous level

So if you define the same configuration at the system level it will be overridden by any same configuration defined at `global` and `local` will override those 2

### [image]

#### Find out where the config value is defined

#### `--show-scope`

Since Git 2.26.0, you can use `--show-scope` option:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.26.0.txt

> - "git config" learned to show in which "scope", in addition to in
>   which file, each config setting comes from.

```
git config --list --show-scope
```

#### `--show-origin`

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

---

Here is a list of the configurations and their location

[image]